# How can I used nested loops to print a matrix of numbers in Python?

Tags: python

For instance, if I have a function and say the input is a number n (i.e. 5)

I want a 5x5 matrix thats like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2       10
3       15
4       20
5 10 15 20 25
```

and how can I write this if I only want the outer most square or the inner most?

(This is for python)

What I tried:

```
def f4(n): 
    for i in range(1, n): 
        for j in range(1, n):
            print i*j, 
        print
```

Comment: have you made some attempt yourself?

Comment: Yes, the problem I was working on was a little different, but what I did was:def f4(n):
 for i in range(1, n):
  for j in range(1, n):
   print i*j,
  print

Comment: But if I just want the outer border, how can I get that?

Comment: add any code you have tried to your question, you will get a better response if you show what you have already tried

Comment: what output do you want, that in your question or something else? What is the outer border?

Comment: Something else, I just want to be able to produce a matrix border using nested loops, the output from the problem I was working on was supposed to be: 1,2,3,...n, 2,4,6,8... etc but in matrix form

Comment: add what output you expect to your question

Comment: Okay, I changed my question to exactly what I want, how can I do this using nested loops?

Answer (score 0):

To control spacing in strings, try [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). For example:

```
>>> print '{:2} {:2} {:2} {:2} {:2}\n{:2} {:2} {:2} {:2} {:2}'.format(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
 1  2  3  4  5
10 20 30 40 50
```

Another hint: it looks like you have 2 types of rows- top/bottom rows and middle rows. The top/bottom rows have a similar format that's different from the middle rows, which are themselves similar.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
% cat squar.py
def squarpy(n, length=5):
    fmt = "%%%dd"%(length)
    sp = " "*length
    square = " ".join([fmt%(i+1) for i in range(n)])
    for j in range(2,n):
        row = " ".join([fmt%(i*j+j) if i==0 or i==n-1 else sp for i in range(n)])
        square = square +"\n" + row
    tail = " ".join([fmt%(i*n+n) for i in range(n)])
    square = square + "\n" + tail
    return square

print squarpy(3)
print
print squarpy(5)
% python2 squar.py
    1     2     3
    2           6
    3     6     9

    1     2     3     4     5
    2                      10
    3                      15
    4                      20
    5    10    15    20    25
%
```

Comment: @user3593822 (and all beginners reading this comment...) The code is so plain that I forgot to explain it, but if you're new to python there are a couple of things that could leave you as a beginner a little puzzled... if this were the case just ask and I'll edit my answer accordingly.